# Downloading images from URL more efficiently

Tags: java, download

Situation: I have an `ArrayList<String>` containing a bunch of links to images (http:/www.foo.com/bar/image1.jpg, http:/www.foo.com/bar/image2.png,... etc)

I have found a working piece of code in order to download them one by one:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            int counter = 1;
            for (String image : imagesList) {
                controller.setDownloadStatusTextArea("Downloading image " + counter + " of " + imagesList.size());
                URL u = new URL(image);
                URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
                String contentType = uc.getContentType();
                int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
                InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
                byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
                int bytesRead;
                int offset = 0;
                while (offset < contentLength) {
                    bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, data.length - offset);
                    if (bytesRead == -1)
                        break;
                    offset += bytesRead;
                }
                in.close();
                if (offset != contentLength) {
                    throw new IOException("Only read " + offset + " bytes; Expected " + contentLength + " bytes");
                }
                String[] tmp = image.split("/");
                String filename = tmp[tmp.length - 1];
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                out.write(data);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                counter++;
            }
            controller.setDownloadStatusTextArea("Download complete");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            controller.setDownloadStatusTextArea("Download failed");
        }
    }
```

This is the first time I'm doing something like this in Java, and I have a feeling this code can be much more efficient by moving a bunch of variables outside of the for loop. But I'm not sure which can be safely moved outside without affecting the functionality and/or performance (both in a negative or positive way). An insight in this situation would be greatly appreciated.
Also: Can I specify where the files need to be downloaded to? Now they just appear in the project folder, I want the user to be able to change his download folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can't be made much more time-efficient.

Think of it this way: even if you polished every last dispensable opcode out it, the time it takes for the JVM to execute this portion of code is not significant at all. The real delay will be in waiting for the data to arrive through the network.

It could be more space-efficient, but I don't think it's necessary.

**Edit**: what you *can* do is download multiple images at the same time, using threads. If the code above looks complicated though, I would advise against it: take some more time to learn your way around the language.

Comment: So it doesn't really matter that I create and destroy the objects I use in every iteration?

Comment: The only object that could become an issue is the array. If I'm not mistaken, Java zero-initializes that array, which could be bothersome for large files. I don't think that's your case, though.

Comment: Don't optimize before it becomes necessary. If this code brings you trouble later on and you'd like to make it faster, you could move your buffer (the array) outside the loop, fix its size at a comfortable number, and write to a file each time it's full.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocte a byte array for whole image... you only need a small buffer - e.g. 8 kB.
Then, read 8 kB from the connection, and write into the FileOutputStream, in a loop.

To make whole code simpler (kick out the loops), you can use e.g.
[Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)
(click on FRAMES link to see whole javadoc).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. Does it really make that much of a difference?

Comment: @Matthias: If you're downloading images which are potentially larger than JVM's available heap memory, then, yes, that would definitely make difference. Otherwise the enduser will face an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I'm downloading them from a public imageboard, none of them are extremely large.

Comment: @Matthias, You're sentenced to 5 minutes of self-reflection for breaking the 1st law of programming: . . .  **Never assume anything**.

Comment: And one more note - don't focus on micro-optimizations. Focus on code simplicity and readability. As noted in other answer, you could make it download in threads, but that's another level.

Comment: "Never assume anything" about the input, I meant. ;-)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've never taken that in account because I've never made any "large" apps yet :) Thx

Answer (score 1):

In a Swing application to let the user select a directory, instantiate a `JFileChooser` with `setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)`.

You could move all the variable declarations outside of the loop as long as you ensure they are properly initialized with each iteration. You won't save a lot of time relative to the time it will take to download and save the file though.

Comment: It's a Swing application. And don't worry, all the validation is happening elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the JFileChooser, but not about the DIRECTORIES_ONLY, thanks. And it just hit me that I just need to add the path to the filename in order to save the files on a different location :)